# How do I set table header cells to have the same width as columns?

Tags: html, css, json, css-tables

I'm using Handlebars.js, requiring data from a JSON file, meaning that this table must be dynamic.

I've already configured the table to display the JSON file properly, however, I'm having some CSS issues as I'm not being able to align the headers with the rows. I've reproduced the issue on a small environment in this Code Pen (http://codepen.io/OPaiTaCa/pen/rjowYm)

I believe that this can be fixed by arranging the CSS file

```
    table.content {
      width: auto;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    th {
      border: 2px solid black;
      display: inline;
    }

   tbody tr {
      float: left;
    }

    tbody td {
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing float and display lines from your CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the reply
What do you mean by the fault theader block?
ceruleus, if I do that, it'll stop displaying data properly.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline` and `display: block` both remove the default `table-cell` property from `th`  and `tr` which is essential for table layout. Erase both, and also erase `float: left` - it is meaningless in this context.

ADDITION: I hadn't looked at your codepen first: Your number of `th`cells is different from your number of `td`per row.  It either has to be the same number/amount of cells in every row (including the header) or you have to use `rowspan` attrubutes for cells that should span several rows.